# Usage of よって in this sentence

Tags: usage, て-form

I am currently doing some exercises for my Japanese class, but they are all in hiragana, which is sometimes irritating, but in this sentence I fail to see the meaning　and thus unable to pick the suitable answer, 3:

ゆうびんきょくに　＿＿　かえります。

Available answers are :

1) やんで　2) よんで　3) よって 4) やって

I thought ~による was used in a sense similar to "According to..." but I really don't see how this fits within the sentence.

Is this another usage of the above form ?

A different verb ? I really think it is more of a suite of actions, "Do something at the post office and come back". I really wish I had a kanji there to help me out... As a bonus, why do textbooks often contain no kanjis and only hiragana ? This seems more confusing that anything else to me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this よって comes from the verb 寄る{よる} which means "to visit, to drop by" in this case. Your sentence thus means:

> ゆうびんきょくによってかえります。
>   I'll drop by the post office and come back.

---

～によると is used as "according to" (see [よると or よれば？ Which one is "according to"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15940/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-or-%E3%82%88%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%EF%BC%9F-which-one-is-according-to/15941#15941)).

～によって can mean "by way/method", "depending on", "because of" (see [What´s the difference between による, により and　によって?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/what%C2%B4s-the-difference-between-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A-and%E3%80%80%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6)).

Neither of them can be applied to "post office" in this sentence though.

Comment: This seems great, thanks! I got confused from this ~によって and the related lesson. Moreover, my dictionary gave me "to approach" as first sense which seemed unrelated...